# How to iterate through every row/column of df to see whether 0 or ' ' present?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a main `df` and I want to iterate through every row and column, checking for 0's and `''`.  I need to output the row where this appears. The trouble is that one is `int` and the other is `str`. So I've made subsets call `cols` and `df_string`, for all `int` columns and `str` respectively.

Can I check the whole `df` at once for `str` and `int` at the same time or do I need to do this separately?

This is my code:

```
cols = ['ID', 'Line Manager Id', 'Project ID']
df_strings = ['Email', 'Name', 'Department']
i = 0
k = 0
for i, j in df.iterrows():
    if df[cols[i]][j] == 0:
        print(i)
        print('incomplete')
    if df[df_strings[i]][j] == '':
        print(i)
        print('incomplete')
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1):

You can do it at same time with `where`， after `stack` the index is the columns which contain the 0 or blank

```
s=df.eq(0)|df.eq('')
df.where(df.eq(0)|df.eq('')).stack()
```

Comment: Im stuck now on next step. How would I iterate using the above, for example, if s ==  True, output the corresponding email from the corresponding row ie df['Email']  or df.where and get email with this output corresponding row. Many thanks